# How should a time period be represented in SQL?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm using ASP.NET MVC4 and SQL Server 2008.

I've got a business requirement that requires equipment to be service after X amount of time. Different equipment items require different amounts of lengths of time before servicing.

In the database, I need to store the period in which equipment needs to be serviced, as well as the next service date.

On the equipment edit screen, I need a dropdown box with options to allow the user to select a **ServiceInterval**. It would actually be preferable not to have a fixed dropdown with times, but I'm not sure how else to do this.

- 3 Months
- 6 Months
- 9 Months
- 1 Year
- 1.5 years
- 2 years
- 3 years
- 4 years
- 5 years

Clicking on a "Serviced" button should Add the **ServiceInterval** to the current date and put that in the **NextServiceDue** field.

What is the best way to store this information, and is there a good way to do this?

Thank you,
Mike

Comment: It depends if, for example, by 3 months you mean 3 times 30 days or 3 months depending on the length of months from the current date.

Comment: I don't mind. What's the best way?

Comment: If you don't mind just use the answer given by @Joshua

Comment: There are not may great ways but several hazardous ways, such as storing "3 months" in the DB without recognizing the possibility of user requirement change after years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what level of granularity you want, but you create a table in the database with the name and the number of seconds or days.

From there, when the user selects the item, just date `DateTime.Now.AddDays(userInput);` or `DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(userInput);`. You can store the interval period along with the serviceable item as well.

Comment: A combination of days, months, and years would provide a flexible solution. It would allow you to run every X days, or every X days and Y months, or every X months, etc. Similar to how cron jobs are defined, if you're familiar with them.

Comment: @Mike: that would definitely work as well. I was going for simplicity with a small(er) number of intervals in which mine would be a bit easier to implement.

Comment: I figured you were, but thought I'd add the extra possibilities in case they were not considered. I'm a different Mike btw, in case you were wondering why *I* hadn't accepted your answer :)

Comment: Haha, yeah, I figured it out - you didn't get the special OP blue in the comments. :)  Another advantage of using a finer granularity (days, hours, minutes, seconds, etc.) is you can create a TimeSpan using one of the convenience methods too: `TimeSpan.FromDays`, etc..